# PHP - Oracle regular expression

Tags: php, regex, oracle

I build formula for Oracle execute. But I not good regular.

```
(CLICK/10)/IMPRESSION => DECODE(IMPRESSION,0,0,(CLICK/10)/IMPRESSION)


RESPONSE/REQUEST    =>  DECODE(REQUEST,0,0,RESPONSE/REQUEST)


CLICK/REQUEST/IMPRESSION = DECODE(IMPRESSION,0,0,DECODE(REQUEST,0,0,CLICK/REQUEST)/IMPRESSION)
```

Please help me 1 solution or 1 pattern for PHP.

Comment: and your question is .. ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear what you're trying to solve. Please **edit your question** to clarify the input data and what output you desire from that input. Explain your business logic. It is easier for us to understand that than to reverse engineer your business logic from some invalid code.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to do it using CASE..WHEN..END as it is more readable and easy to debug.

See Your answer and my answer as following:

```
(CLICK/10)/IMPRESSION 
Your method => DECODE(IMPRESSION,0,0,(CLICK/10)/IMPRESSION)
My Method => (CLICK/10)/(CASE WHEN IMPRESSION = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IMPRESSION END)

RESPONSE/REQUEST    
Your method =>  DECODE(REQUEST,0,0,RESPONSE/REQUEST)
My Method => RESPONSE/(CASE WHEN REQUEST = 0 THEN 1 ELSE REQUEST END)


CLICK/REQUEST/IMPRESSION 
Your method => DECODE(IMPRESSION,0,0,DECODE(REQUEST,0,0,CLICK/REQUEST)/IMPRESSION)
My Method => CLICK/(CASE WHEN REQUEST = 0 THEN 1 ELSE REQUEST END)/(CASE WHEN IMPRESSION = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IMPRESSION END)
```

Cheers!!

Comment: That is 1 good solution.
With case :
CLICK/(10/IMPRESSION/(REQUEST*10))
Please help me.

Comment: `CLICK/(10/(CASE WHEN IMPRESSION = 0 THEN 1 ELSE IMPRESSION END)/((CASE WHEN REQUEST = 0 THEN 1 ELSE REQUEST END)*10)) `